# Como usar imagens svg?

Tags: svg

Não estou entendo e nem conseguindo usar imagens `svg` numa aplicação web.

Baixei a imagem `https://svgur.com/i/8NF.svg` e a coloquei na `<img src="8NF.svg" class="logo"/>`, mas ela não aparece.

Só aparece se quando coloco a `url` da imagem na `<img src="https://svgur.com/i/8NF.svg" class="logo"/>`.

Quando acesso localmente `localhost:5555/8NF.svg` pelo navegador, a imagem também aparece normalmente. Então a imagem está lá.

Já revisei diversas vezes o código, e não acredito que seja problema nele. Mas também não sei qual outro problema seria.

```html
<style>
.logo {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
</style>

<p>Desta forma funciona.</p>
<p><img src="https://svgur.com/i/8NF.svg" class="logo" /></p>

<p>Já assim, não aparece a imagem.</p>
<p><img src="8NF.svg" class="logo" /></p>
```

Comment: O servidor está retornando o SVG com o MIME type correto?

Comment: Recomendo colocar também seu código HTML aqui para verificarmos outro eventual problema.

Comment: Não sei o que é _MIME type_, nem como verificar isso. Vou dar uma pesquisada. Obrigado!

Comment: Já verificou se não tem algum CSS interferindo na imagem, ou no container que a imagem está dentro? Se vc consegue acessar pela URL é pq ela está lá... provavelmente tem um display:none, opacity:0, position:absolute ou algo assim tirando a imagem do stage. Até mesmo se ela estiver com o `fill` branco #fff pode ser que vc não esteja percebendo ela na tela... Verifique as classes etc, as vezes resolve

Comment: Isso é o MIME tipe `type="image/svg+xml"` e aparentemente está certo, apesar de que usar imagem.svg na tag imagem não precisa declarar MIME type, então deveria estar funcionando, acreito que seu problema é algo referente ao que disse acima...

Comment: Então, está como no exemplo que postei. Não possuo nenhum css.

Comment: Vc realmente tem a necessidade de usar o svg dentro da tag `<object>` ou vc colocou só pq quis?

Comment: Estou procurando um servidor para fazer upload da imagem que tenho. Pois essa do exemplo parece estar funcionando do jeito que eu gostaria que funcionasse com a imagem original que possuo. Está tudo tão confuso. Vou fazer mais alguns testes pelo `localhost`. A página ser PHP interfere em algo?

Comment: Ser .PHP não muda nada. Vc pode colocar o código que está dentro do .svg direto no CodePen ou JSfidelle, ai a gente pega o código e salva localmente como .svg, acho que fica mais fácil do que subir o .svg pro host

Comment: Ah, entendi agora. Tem um código dentro do SVG. Eu ainda não tinha mexido com esta extensão. Então o problema pode estar dentro do SVG? Vou tentar postar o código fonte da imagem.

Comment: Este é o código do SVG http://jsfiddle.net/d0wohutf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei a solução para meu problema!

O MIME Type não estava definido no servidor. Adicionei as seguintes linhas de código no arquivo `.htaccess`.

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg
AddType image/svg+xml svgz
```

Fonte: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/513485-svg-n%C3%A3o-renderizando/

Comment: Boa jovem isso ai

Comment: Obrigado, Hugo!

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente não havia problemas como o seu SVG, ele tinha alguns detalhes, mas nada que impedisse a renderização. Então acredito que o problema é a forma como vc está trabalhando com o `arquivo.svg`

Repare no código abaixo que eu coloquei o SVG direito dentro do código. Mas ai localmente vc pode pegar tudo que estiver dentro das tags `<svg></svg>` copia e cola dentro de um `Bloco de Notas`, salva como `.txt` mesmo, e depois renomeia o arquivo de `minhaimagem.txt` para `minhaimagem.svg`. pronto vc terá seu SVG salvo para poder indexar no documento.

Repare também que qualquer `width` e `height` que vc colocar no `Style` é o que fica valendo pro `<svg>`, mesmo ele tendo uma largura e altura definidos inline, o CSS sobrescreve esses valores!

Repare também que o SVG por default preserva o aspect-ratio, e ele não vai ocupar o *container* inteiro pois vc está colocando uma imagem quadrada dentro de um retângulo, se vc quiser mudar isso vc precisa setar lá dentro do seu `.svg` `preserveAspectRatio="none"` na tag `<svg>`

Para ver como fica veja o exemplo abaixo.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
svg {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 64vw;
    height: 64vh;
}    
svg.quadrado {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
SVG com o aspect-ratio preservado<br><br>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="512px" height="512px">
    <g>
        <circle style="fill:#0053AB" cx="256" cy="256" r="256" data-original="#0053AB" class="" data-old_color="#44C4FC"/>
        <path style="fill:#0B3660" d="M512,256c0-10.491-0.646-20.83-1.872-30.99l-99.507-99.507L78,361l149.401,149.401  C236.792,511.445,246.331,512,256,512C397.385,512,512,397.385,512,256z" data-original="#0B3660" class="" data-old_color="#29ACE5"/>
        <rect x="101.38" y="125.5" style="fill:#37474F;" width="309.24" height="215.99" data-original="#37474F" class=""/>
        <rect x="255.95" y="125.5" style="fill:#263238;" width="154.67" height="215.99" data-original="#263238" class=""/>
        <rect x="119.3" y="141.78" style="fill:#FEA626;" width="273.4" height="183.45" data-original="#FEA626" class=""/>
        <rect x="255.95" y="141.78" style="fill:#F47C00;" width="136.75" height="183.45" data-original="#F47C00" class=""/>
        <path style="fill:#1E499E" d="M285.026,166.246v65.458h-58.052v-65.458c-19.361,10.373-32.534,30.792-32.534,54.294  c0,23.533,13.21,43.975,32.615,54.334v50.349h57.893v-50.348c19.404-10.36,32.614-30.801,32.614-54.335  C317.561,197.039,304.387,176.619,285.026,166.246z" data-original="#1E499E" class=""/>
        <path style="fill:#0E387C" d="M317.561,220.54c0-23.501-13.174-43.921-32.535-54.294v65.458h-29.074v93.519h28.994v-50.348  C304.351,264.515,317.561,244.074,317.561,220.54z" data-original="#0E387C" class=""/>
        <rect x="78" y="319.67" style="fill:#455A64" width="356" height="41.33" data-original="#455A64" class=""/>
        <rect x="255.95" y="319.67" style="fill:#37474F;" width="178.05" height="41.33" data-original="#37474F" class=""/>
    </g>
</svg>

<br><br>

SVG sem o aspect-ratio preservado<br><br>

<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" viewBox="0 0 512 512" >
    <g>
        <circle style="fill:#0053AB" cx="256" cy="256" r="256" data-original="#0053AB" class="" data-old_color="#44C4FC"/>
        <path style="fill:#0B3660" d="M512,256c0-10.491-0.646-20.83-1.872-30.99l-99.507-99.507L78,361l149.401,149.401  C236.792,511.445,246.331,512,256,512C397.385,512,512,397.385,512,256z" data-original="#0B3660" class="" data-old_color="#29ACE5"/>
        <rect x="101.38" y="125.5" style="fill:#37474F;" width="309.24" height="215.99" data-original="#37474F" class=""/>
        <rect x="255.95" y="125.5" style="fill:#263238;" width="154.67" height="215.99" data-original="#263238" class=""/>
        <rect x="119.3" y="141.78" style="fill:#FEA626;" width="273.4" height="183.45" data-original="#FEA626" class=""/>
        <rect x="255.95" y="141.78" style="fill:#F47C00;" width="136.75" height="183.45" data-original="#F47C00" class=""/>
        <path style="fill:#1E499E" d="M285.026,166.246v65.458h-58.052v-65.458c-19.361,10.373-32.534,30.792-32.534,54.294  c0,23.533,13.21,43.975,32.615,54.334v50.349h57.893v-50.348c19.404-10.36,32.614-30.801,32.614-54.335  C317.561,197.039,304.387,176.619,285.026,166.246z" data-original="#1E499E" class=""/>
        <path style="fill:#0E387C" d="M317.561,220.54c0-23.501-13.174-43.921-32.535-54.294v65.458h-29.074v93.519h28.994v-50.348  C304.351,264.515,317.561,244.074,317.561,220.54z" data-original="#0E387C" class=""/>
        <rect x="78" y="319.67" style="fill:#455A64" width="356" height="41.33" data-original="#455A64" class=""/>
        <rect x="255.95" y="319.67" style="fill:#37474F;" width="178.05" height="41.33" data-original="#37474F" class=""/>
    </g>
</svg>

<br><br>

SVG sem o aspect-ratio preservado, mas corrigido usando altura e largura iguais<br><br>

<svg class="quadrado" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="512px" height="512px">
    <g>
        <circle style="fill:#0053AB" cx="256" cy="256" r="256" data-original="#0053AB" class="" data-old_color="#44C4FC"/>
        <path style="fill:#0B3660" d="M512,256c0-10.491-0.646-20.83-1.872-30.99l-99.507-99.507L78,361l149.401,149.401  C236.792,511.445,246.331,512,256,512C397.385,512,512,397.385,512,256z" data-original="#0B3660" class="" data-old_color="#29ACE5"/>
        <rect x="101.38" y="125.5" style="fill:#37474F;" width="309.24" height="215.99" data-original="#37474F" class=""/>
        <rect x="255.95" y="125.5" style="fill:#263238;" width="154.67" height="215.99" data-original="#263238" class=""/>
        <rect x="119.3" y="141.78" style="fill:#FEA626;" width="273.4" height="183.45" data-original="#FEA626" class=""/>
        <rect x="255.95" y="141.78" style="fill:#F47C00;" width="136.75" height="183.45" data-original="#F47C00" class=""/>
        <path style="fill:#1E499E" d="M285.026,166.246v65.458h-58.052v-65.458c-19.361,10.373-32.534,30.792-32.534,54.294  c0,23.533,13.21,43.975,32.615,54.334v50.349h57.893v-50.348c19.404-10.36,32.614-30.801,32.614-54.335  C317.561,197.039,304.387,176.619,285.026,166.246z" data-original="#1E499E" class=""/>
        <path style="fill:#0E387C" d="M317.561,220.54c0-23.501-13.174-43.921-32.535-54.294v65.458h-29.074v93.519h28.994v-50.348  C304.351,264.515,317.561,244.074,317.561,220.54z" data-original="#0E387C" class=""/>
        <rect x="78" y="319.67" style="fill:#455A64" width="356" height="41.33" data-original="#455A64" class=""/>
        <rect x="255.95" y="319.67" style="fill:#37474F;" width="178.05" height="41.33" data-original="#37474F" class=""/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

---

**DICA**

Quando vc indexar seu SVG no documento use apenas a tag `<img>` e trate os estilos dessa imagem como altura e largura direto pelo CSS

Veja o exemplo:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
img {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 64vw;
    height: 64vh;
}
```

```html
SVG externo indexado<br><br>

<img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/410.svg" alt="">
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu trabalho arduo. Mas ainda não consegui fazer funcionar aqui. Copiei o terceiro código, coloquei em um bloco de notas, salvei como teste.txt e depois renomeei para teste.svg. Depois coloquei em um <img src="teste.svg" class="imagem"> e no css coloquei img.imagem {width:64vw;height:64vh;}. Continua aparecendo um quadrado de 500 por 500 vazio.

Comment: Colocando o código direto no html, daí funciona. Mas eu queria usar o arquivo.svg mesmo. Você sabe como colocar aquele códgio em um arquivo.svg que dê para ser colocadado no src de uma tag img? Obrigado!

Comment: @PauloDosSantos Verifica se o seu editor de código, se é o Atom, Sublime, VS Code etc, verifique se ele salva arquivos como .SVG, se sim, abra um documento novo, coloque o código da primeira tag `<svg></svg>` e salve direto do edito como imagem.svg, pode ser que salvando pelo Bloco de Notas tenha dado algum problema... E copiei o código desse SVG direto da minha resposta no VS Code e salvei como SVG, depois chamei como <img ... .svg> e funcionou certinho

Comment: Já revisei tudo, diversas vezes. Mas ainda não consegui fazer a imagem aparecer.

Comment: @PauloDosSantos cara pega o "miolo" do seu SVG e coloca dentro dessa tag e salva como .SVG, depois abre no browser. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="284px" height="284px" viewBox="0 0 284 284" style="enable-background:new 0 0 284 284;"
  xml:space="preserve"> ... </svg>` Verifique aqui se o seu browser da suporte ao svg https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg

Comment: Verifiquei e dá suporte sim. Também coloquei no Sublime o código, salvei, abri o arquivo no navegador, consegui ver a imagem, mas não exibe quandoe stá dentro do `<img src="imagem.svg" style="width:512px;height:512px;" />`. É como se o navegador não encontrasse a imagem (igual no exemplo que eu repostei hoje).

Comment: @PauloDosSantos Vc colocou a imagem na pasta correta? Não tem outro css na página tipo img {display:none} ? Vc verificou na Aba Network do Devtools se a imagem aparece ou da algum erro (entra no devtool aperta F12, vai na aba Network e da um F5 e olha se a image aparece na listagem)?

Comment: https://ctrlv.cz/oFgP

Comment: Será que é questão de servidor?

Comment: Primeiro testa localmente e ve se funciona. Lá pelo visto está retornando um Status 304 olha o que é https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304 ... parece que é Cache

Comment: Não deve ser isso! https://ctrlv.cz/wmke

Comment: Eu até dei um `<?=file_get_contents("logo.svg")?>` com PHP, e a imagem aparece perfeitamente. Mas gostaria de usar tag HTML `<img src="logo.svg" class="logo" />`.

Comment: @PauloDosSantos agora parece que retornou um 200, era pra imagem tem aparecido... Não sei dizer pq não rolou... Aqui localmente com o seu código e a imagem do link funcionou normalmente

Comment: Acho que é problema no servidor! Vou testar esta solução aqui: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/513485-svg-n%C3%A3o-renderizando/

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo tempo que você gastou tentando me ajudar. Realmente tudo o que você me disse funcionou localmente, mas não funcionou no servidor. Como eu não entendo nada disso, fica até difícil explicar o que está acontecendo.

Comment: @PauloDosSantos tranquilo jovem, boa sorte ai! Se conseguir a solução depois posta ai pra comunidade

Comment: Obrigado! Irei postar sim! :)